# Copying non-existent resources during iPhone build

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

At one point in my iPhone app development, I had 2 rather large video files as resources for use in the app. After some tests, I decided I didn't want them anymore. So I deleted both from the resources folder in xcode - and I selected 'remove and delete selected references.' When I try to build on my iPhone or iPad, it still says "copying file opening.mov to iPhone." And it takes up space in the build.

What is happening? I deleted all references to the file everywhere on my computer, but it still copies the file on my iDevices.

I checked the xcode project folder in finder and it's not there!

Comment: try *cleaning* your target (e.g. under the "Product" menu, choose "Clean") and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to Project->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources, chances are those files are still there somehow, delete them if they are.

Additionally as suggested do a product clean.

Comment: It was the clean that did it!

Answer (score 0):

Go to /Users/your user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/your version/Applications and delete the folder for your app.

Hint: Library could be a hidden folder. If you not see it use tinker tools to make the folder visible.

Delete the app on your test device.

In xcode go to Build Phases and check if your file is copied to bundle resources. If yes - delete it from there.

Clean your build an run.